# Issues in installing Ionic framework on Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: node.js, macos, cordova, ionic-framework, failed-installation

I am trying to install Ionic framework on my mac-mini having Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10). As per the http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/

1. Installed Node.js from https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7.pkg
2. After that I ran following command from terminal $ sudo npm install -g cordova ionic

But I am getting following issues:

```
rohits-Mac-mini:~ rohitdhamija$ sudo npm install -g cordova ionic

npm WARN engine cordova-js@4.0.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.7","npm":"2.13.3"})

npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.12.7","npm":"2.13.3"})

npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree

npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.7","npm":"2.13.3"})

/usr/local/bin/cordova -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova

npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0

npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"

npm ERR! node v0.12.7

npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3

npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET

npm ERR! sys call read
```

I saw some similar post on SO, but it did not solve the issue. Would be great if someone help in the same.

**Update:**
I tried to install cordova, it got successfully installed. After that i tried installing ionic, but it DIDNOT get install.

```
rohits-Mac-mini:~ rohitdhamija$ npm -v
2.13.3
rohits-Mac-mini:~ rohitdhamija$ node -v
v0.12.7
rohits-Mac-mini:~ rohitdhamija$ cordova -v
5.1.1
```

Below is the detailed log

```
rohits-Mac-mini:~ rohitdhamija$ sudo npm install -g ionic
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

  [Restored]
```

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo npm install -g cordova` and `sudo npm install -g cordova`, separately? What happens if you install Node.js via Homebrew instead of manually?

Comment: cordova got installed, but ionic had same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to be the issue with my service provider. I switched from BSNL network to Airtel and tried again. It installed successfully! It seemed BSNL disabled some server data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it looks that the problem mostly comes from the service provider.
I switched the internet providers and everything worked, bit strange but it is a solution.

Comment: My service provider blocked some of common sites,,,and hence was not able to install